# Setting ARIMA model parameters

Tags: python, prediction, statsmodels, arima

I have daily data representing the number of customers according to date as follows:
[number of daily customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpHZJ.png)

I want to make predictions for the number of customers based on this data.

I tried ARIMA and AUTOARIMA to set the order parameters, But, the result is not as good as I wanted:

```
model = pm.auto_arima(df_prediction['Number of Tickets'], 
                      test='adf',
                      seasonal=False,
                      m=100,
                      trace=True,
                      error_action='ignore',  
                      suppress_warnings=True, 
                      stepwise=True)
```

The results were like this:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdKmP.png)
Is there a better model for such prediction or there is a better configuration for this model?

Comment: This might be the wrong place to ask the question, since it's not about code. However, how are you choosing the value for `m`? I see "The period for seasonal differencing, m refers to the number of periods in each season. For example, m is 4 for quarterly data, 12 for monthly data, or 1 for annual (non-seasonal) data. Default is 1. " if you're using https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html. 100 seems rather large